# Дефектная ссылка в справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

Конкретно — в [разделе лицензирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing):

> ...При использовании
>   материалов с сайтов на Stack Exchange, [требуется обязательное
>   указание
>   авторства].(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Я так понимаю, должно быть так (убрал точку между `]` и `(`):

> ...При использовании материалов с сайтов на Stack Exchange, [требуется обязательное указание авторства](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Поправил, теперь все отображается как должно.